# Why does emptying the trash in Snow Leopard take so long?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, trash

Since installing Mac OS X 10.6, whenever I empty the trash, it takes about 50x as long as it used to under 10.5.  I just emptied about 100 files (totaling 50 megs / all local files), and it was about 20 minutes.

It feels like its doing a secure delete, but I'm just using the "Empty Trash" option (click on bin -- choose empty trash).  Is it possible that the secure delete is turned on by default?

Comment: That is strange. I found Snow Leopard to be much quicker emptying the trash as I've move backups around with lots of files and end up deleting them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to **Finder** » **Preferences**, and in the Advanced tab uncheck **Empty Trash Securely**.

The default did not change for me, but for some unknown reason [it did change for some](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10064246) [people](http://teravoxel.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/is-your-trash-emptying-slow-in-leopard-or-snow-leopard/).

Comment: Omg, thank you! I thought FileVault for some reason forced me to empty my trash securely, which totally doesn't make sense. Now I don't have to wait for hours before the trash is emptied.